# Drivers issue? poor youtube video quality after using Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, proprietary

I switched my os from Windows to Ubuntu. Thereafter, the youtube video quality worsen. I wonder whether that is a driver issue or not because I skip the enable installing "third party software" during the Ubuntu installing process.

My computer has the following description with the additional drivers not being properly installed (or identified). It displays "Intel Corporation: Unknown".

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and here is my spec:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: i915 tty: N/A 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
```

[image: Software Updates - Additional Drivers Tab]

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: I don't see any "issue". Some oem package is installed, that is OK.

Comment: The alternate drivers [are for Dell hardware](https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-focal-fossa/package/oem-somerville-warcraft-intel-meta) that has been certified by Canonical. These meta packages ensure that the OS can take advantage of the hardware in the notebook. If you are concerned about the "Unknown" bits, please [edit] your question to let us know what is not working 